# Permanently authorize a Google Sheets

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-sheets

I'm making a project that involves an App Engine (Java) Server that creates a spreadsheet on a weekly basis. The spreadsheet will be created on behalf of an actual Google user.

**How do I configure my app to be given permanent[1] access to read/write/create a Google Sheets?**
Can I use the same method[1] to access my user's Google Sheets permanently?

[1]The app is currently using a permanent (until revoked) access to the Admin API. I need a similar kind of OAuth2. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Same problem here.